# Im making a discord bot and when i do this specific embed in the cog, it throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, traceback

So ive got the cog working and when i do other embeds in the cog then they work but for this specific embed it doesnt work. I get a traceback error and the last part of the error says "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer"

````
from discord.ext import commands

class pingcog(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def ping(self, ctx):
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//", case_insensitive=True)

    ping_embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x003f7f)
    ping_embed.add_field(name = "Ping Command", value = f"Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms", inline = False)
    ping_embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed = ping_embed)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(pingcog(client))```
````

Comment: Why are you adding `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//", case_insensitive=True)` into the command? That does not make any sense...

Comment: @Dominik i did that because if i didnt then i would get a red line under the ```client.latency * 1000)}ms", inline = False)``` which is indicating an error

Comment: You defined `self.client = client`, why are you not using that?

Comment: @Domink i did but when i delete ```client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//", case_insensitive=True)``` it gives me another error

Comment: Use `ping_embed.add_field(name = "Ping Command", value = f"Pong! {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms", inline = False)` and delete `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "//", case_insensitive=True)`?